# Can't find a way to reduce 2 SQL queries to 1 without killing performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query which works absolutely fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT `fk_match_id`) 
  FROM `pass` 
  WHERE `passer` IN ('48717','33305','49413','1640') 
  AND `receiver` IN ('48717','33305','49413','1640');
```

The numbers in the IN clause are player ID's, and can be obtained from another table in the database called player. Each row in this table has a player ID, a team_id and a match_id which is a foreign key to the match table.

I would like to automatically obtain those player ID's using the match_id. I can do this as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT `fk_match_id`) 
  FROM `pass` 
  WHERE `passer` IN 
  (
    SELECT player_id 
      FROM `player` 
      WHERE `team_id` = someTeamID  
      AND `match_id` = someMatchID) 
      AND `receiver` IN 
      (
        SELECT player_id 
          FROM `player` 
          WHERE `team_id` = someTeamID  
          AND `match_id` = someMatchID
      )
  )
```

However, apparentyly using subqueries is infamously slow and indeed, it's far too slow to use. Even using join, as follows, is far too slow:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT `fk_match_id`) 
  from `pass` st1 
  INNER JOIN `player` st2 
  ON (st1.passer = st2.player_id OR st1.receiver = st2.player_id);
```

That too, is far too slow. So want to know if it is possible to do what I can do in 2 queries in effectively 0.0 seconds (fetching the players id's in one query and then running the first query takes virtually no time at all) in just one query, or if that is completely impossible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT::

The relevant table structures are as follows:

Player:

[image]

Pass:

[image]

I want to calculate the number of passes every player has made to another player in a given line up in history. I have a match id and a team id. I can obtain the players involved in a particular match for a team by querying the player table:

```
SELECT player_id 
  FROM `player` 
  WHERE `team_id` = someTeamID  
  AND `match_id` = someMatchID
```

This returns something like:

> 1803,1930,13310,1764,58845,15157,51938,2160,18892,12002,4101,14668,80979,59013

I then want to query the pass table and return every row where one of those id's is in the passer and the receiver columns.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  And the table layouts?

Comment: There may be a bit of indexing to be done in your field. Are all the *_id fields indexed, as well as receiver and passer?

Comment: I've added more details. They are all index, yes :/

Comment: What is the difference between `player.match_id` and `pass.fk_match_id` column? Do they store different data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a composite index on `(passer, receiver)`:

After adding it, try the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT fk_match_id) 
FROM pass
  INNER JOIN player AS p 
    ON pass.passer = p.player_id
  INNER JOIN player AS r 
    ON r.player_id = pass.passer  ;
```

If you want these results for a specific `(team_id, match_id)` combination, add an `(team_id, match_id, player_id)` index and then use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT fk_match_id) 
FROM pass
  INNER JOIN player AS p 
    ON  p.team_id = someTeamID  
    AND p.match_id` = someMatchID
    AND p.player_id = pass.passer 
  INNER JOIN player AS r
    ON  r.team_id = someTeamID  
    AND r.match_id` = someMatchID
    AND r.player_id = pass.receiver ;
```